# A question about unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m$ be unit vectors in the sphere $S^{n-1}$ s.t.
>   $||v_j-v_k||^2=2$ for $j \neq k$ and $1 \leq j, \leq m$. Then we must have
>
> - $m$ is always greater than $n$.
> - $m$ is at most $2^n$ but may be greater than $n$.
> - $m$ is at most $n$.
> - $m$ can be infinite.

**My work**: I took $n=3$.Then the set $S^2$ with its vectors satisfying $||v_j-v_k||^2=2$ for $j \neq k$ and $1 \leq j, \leq m$  eventually contains only two orthogonal unit vectors viz. $X$ and $Y$ axes. Similarly, I think that for $n=4$, $S^3$ will eventually contains three orthogonal unit vectors viz. $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ axes.But my doubt is that can I generalize this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Can you come up with an example of such set vectors for some sphere? You can fx start with the sphere being a circle. Is there something interesting with the set that strikes you? If you show that you've done **some** attempt at solving the problem it would be more meaningful to help you, and the help would be more useful to you.

Comment: Taking n=3, I got the condition of orthogonality between each vj and vk.From which, I think only 2 vectors qualify. so m=2. Am I correct to select option 3?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. All the vector's has to be pairwise orthogonal. To see this consider $2 = ||v_j-v_k||=(v_j-v_k)^2 = v_j^2+v_k^2 - 2v_j\cdot v_k$ and use the fact that $v_j^2 = ||v_j||^2 = 1$.